# Получить текущее время и дату android

Tags: android, android-studio, дата, simpledateformat

В приложении нужно в два отдельных textview вывести дату и время. Я уже перепробовал все что смог найти на просторах интернета, например:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
textview.setText(format.format(new Date()));

DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy, HH:mm");
String date = df.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
```

и еще много разных примеров, и как результат - у меня либо не выводит ничего в textview или слетает приложение, как ошибку выводит например проблемы с грегорианским календарем или еще что-то в этом роде, ну то есть показывает что проблема в каком глубоком классе, который отвечает за ту функцию что я вызываю, а я не хочу влезать в те классы так как не я их создавал и могу нарушить их работу своим вмешательством. Если кто-то сталкивался с подобными проблемами или знает как решить мою то буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Если в логах ошибках, то вставляйте текст ошибки в код. Ведь может быть так, что вы неверно интерпретируете ее текст.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Оба ваших варианта должны быть рабочими. Пройдитесь по коду отладчиком, посмотрите, что возвращают методы, `SimpleDateFormat.format(...)` должен возвращать форматированное представление даты строкой.

Аналогичный вариант, отдельно дата и время:

```
// Текущее время
Date currentDate = new Date();
// Форматирование времени как "день.месяц.год"
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
String dateText = dateFormat.format(currentDate);
// Форматирование времени как "часы:минуты:секунды"
DateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
String timeText = timeFormat.format(currentDate);

textViewDate.setText(dateText);
textViewTime.setText(timeText);
```

Используемые импорты:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
```

Comment: И куда это все надо вписывать? В какой файл и в каком месте?

Comment: @Rus, где вам нужно получать время и дату там и вставляете, там ниже есть сеттинг текста в текстовое поле, вы же можете делать то что требует ваша задача :)