# Объясните ошибку программы android

Tags: android, android-studio, время, datetime

У меня есть приложение на андроид и в нем мне нужно вывести дату и время в два отдельных textview. Для решения поставленной задачи я использовал ответы и информацию из своего предыдущего вопроса [Получить текущее время и дату android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/852351/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83-android). Я все сделал как мне посоветовали но у меня все равно вывело ошибку и активити не смогло создаться. Вот ошибка которую я получил:

```
07-10 07:40:16.172 11481-11481/com.example.andrew.diplom E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.andrew.diplom, PID: 11481
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.andrew.diplom/com.example.andrew.diplom.Results}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2509)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2569)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:150)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1399)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5885)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.andrew.diplom.Results.onCreate(Results.java:36)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6262)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1125)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2462)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2569) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:150) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1399) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5885) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
```

Я начинающий разработчик приложений, и возможно я неправильно расшифровываю эту ошибку но насколько я вижу проблема в том что я передаю в textview пустое значение null а у меня из кода видно что значение должно быть. Если кто-то сталкивался с подобной ошибкой или знает в чем причина у меня то буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Проблема в том, что у вас не инициализирован сам `TextView`. Посмотрите сами или покажите код, где вы это (не) делаете

Comment: вы не передаете "пустое значение" в виджет. Ваш виджет - "пустое значение". Либо на него не получена ссылка методом `findViewById()`, либо в этом методе указан неправильный ID виджета - это основные причины. Если вы не сможете самостоятельно решить этот вопрос, то к вопросу нужно приложить код и разметку, на которой присутствует  виджет.

Comment: да, я понял скоро отредактирую ответ и приложу свой проблемный код.