# Как вывести дату на экран при открытии приложения?

Tags: android, дата

Пустое первое приложение, банальный ежедневник задуман для тренировки. Нужно чтобы в самом верху отображалась текущая дата, в формате "день недели, день-месяц-год". Во всех ответах здесь советуют использовать метод Date.toString()или класс SimpleDateFormat. Но никто не объясняет как использовать эти методы - в какой файл писать слова Date.toString() или SimpleDateFormat, в каком месте файла это вставлять, что писать в скобки и т.д.

### Простите, для специалистов это наверное смешной вопрос, но я пока еще медный чайник, как научусь - так тупить не буду.

Все удалил. Начал с начала. С тулбаром не получается, потому что скачивать API который мне пока не нужен не могу. В связи с чем, вместо слов "Hello World" планирую видеть текущую дату.

### activity_main.xml сейчас в таком виде:

```
 <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="kz.start.a1st.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/shapka"
        android:layout_width="315dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"tools:text=
         />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

### MainActivity.java выглядит так:

```
package kz.start.a1st;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // globally
        TextView shapka = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.shapka)
        // Текущее время
        Date currentDate = new Date();
        // Форматирование времени как "день.месяц.год"
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
        String dateText = dateFormat.format(currentDate);
        shapka.setText(dateText);

    }
}
```

Вот всё что есть .
[image: Вот то что видно на рабочем столе]

Попробовал запустить эмулятор - не запустился.
[image: ошибки такое выдал]

Проблема была в том, что теперь не обязательно дополнительно приводить
TextView shapka = **(TextView)**findViewById(R.id.shapka)
достаточно писать так:
TextView shapka = findViewById(R.id.shapka).

[Взял отсюда](https://code.briarproject.org/briar/briar/commit/43ee3246f60f5952d2d8ad99f6581dec450c0485)

В общем тыкал тыкал - заработало.

Андрею благодарность за помощь!

Comment: понятное дело что оно не запускается у вас ошибки в коде, вы их искали в гугле, смотрели возможные причины? вот ошибка - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089718/error-error-parsing-xml-not-well-formed-invalid-token, вот еще одна - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/736358/Ошибка-сборки-после-обновления-android-studio, код у вас как я и говорил нормальный, но вы умолчали о том что у вас куча ошибок помимо кода)

Comment: Так я и не запускал эмулятор, пока вы не спросили запускается ли приложение. И соответственно не было этих ошибок. В первом скриншоте написано же 0 ошибок.

Comment: у  вас там все красное, но ошибок нет) странно)) я ссылки приложил с решением ваших ошибок, там все написано, думаю разберетесь)

Comment: Разобрался это громко сказано. Но проверка кода самой Студией очень помогла. Ошибок не было в синтаксисе ни в одном файле. ОЗУхи мало на десктопе, может поэтому эмулятор не запустился. Сейчас ничего красного нет, арк собрался без проблем, установился на телефон и дата выводится в нужном месте.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы вроде видели [данный](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/852351/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83-android/852391#comment1825293_852391) вопрос. У вас есть активность где вы будете писать логику поведение приложения. И есть разметка в layouts папке. По-умолчанию создается activity_main.xml и MainActivity.java (MainActivity.kt). Дальше есть два варианта: либо выбор стиля активности в котором будет использоваться тулбар либо добавить в разметку тулбар. У вас есть разметка, добавляем тулбар:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        style="@style/Toolbar"/>

    <RelativeLayout>

        <!-- Весь контент информации о пользователе -->

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

дальше вот стиль тулбара:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Остальные элементы выше не изменились -->

    <style name="Toolbar">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">?attr/actionBarSize</item>
        <!-- <item name="theme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar</item> -->
        <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Остальные элементы ниже не изменились -->

</resources>
```

вот активность:

```
public class UserInfoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Остальной код выше не изменился

    private Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Остальной код выше не изменился

        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle(ваша дата и время);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        // Остальной код 
    }
}
```

дальше идем в вопрос который вы видели, получаем строки времени и даты:

```
// Текущее время
Date currentDate = new Date();
// Форматирование времени как "день.месяц.год"
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
String dateText = dateFormat.format(currentDate);
// Форматирование времени как "часы:минуты:секунды"
DateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
String timeText = timeFormat.format(currentDate);
```

дальше все просто:

```
  public class UserInfoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Остальной код выше не изменился

    private Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Текущее время
        Date currentDate = new Date();
        // Форматирование времени как "день.месяц.год"
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
        String dateText = dateFormat.format(currentDate);
         // Форматирование времени как "часы:минуты:секунды"
        DateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
        String timeText = timeFormat.format(currentDate);

        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle(dateText);
        toolbar.setSubtitle(timeText)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        // Остальной код 
    }
}
```

и все. [Вот](https://devcolibri.com/unit/%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA-11-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-toolbar-%D0%B8-menu-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5-userinfoactivity/) туториал для работы с тулбаром.

### update

у вас в xml все обернуто в фигурные скобки - так делать не нужно, уберите их сначала и в конце, дальше у вас текстовое поле имеет атрибут - tools:text= - сюда либо нужно что-то написать, либо уберите его вообще.  В активности вы никак не обрабатываете полученную дату. [Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19452681/9363441) ответ, в котором расписано что и как делать :)

Comment: Спасибо Сэнсэй Фигурные скобки это тут редактор сообщения навтыкал пока я код пытался вставить в текст вопроса.  По данной вами ссылке просто введение других текстов вместо Hello World, да и испанский я пока еще не выучил. А -1 к моему вопросу почему, не знаете? Или нельзя вопросы задавать?

Comment: я дал ссылку на ответ, на один определенный ответ

Comment: ну так нужно создать, в xml присвойте полю идентификатор, и дальше в активности создайте переменную этого текстового поля в активности, а приведенном ответе есть пример.

Comment: добавьте в вопрос пожалуйста, а то в комментариях во-первых сложно разбираться, а во вторых сюда никто смотреть не будет