# Приветствие пользователя с использованием TextView

Tags: java, android, android-layout, textview

Как сделать, чтобы при входе в приложение, в определённое время суток (утро, день, ночь) `TextView` отображал определённый текст заданный мной. То есть например:

- утром - 'Доброе утро';
- днём - 'Добрый день';
- ночью - 'Доброй ночи'.

Comment: А проблема в чем? проверяйте текущее время, в зависимости от значения подставляете фразу которая вам нужна

Comment: Так а как? Я дико извиняюсь, новичок в этом ремесле. Поэтому и спрашиваю

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Получить текущее время и дату android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/852351/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8f-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83-android)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно так:

```
 private static final LocalTime DAY_TIME = LocalTime.of(11,0)
 private static final LocalTime EVENING_TIME = LocalTime.of(18,0)
 private static final LocalTime NIGHT_TIME = LocalTime.of(23,0)

 public String getHelloString(LocalTime curTime){
     if(curTime.isBefore(DAY_TIME)){
         return "Доброе утро";
     }if else(curTime.isBefore(EVENING_TIME)){
         return "Добрый день";
     }if else(curTime.isBefore(NIGHT_TIME)){
         return "Добрый вечер";
     }else{
         return "Доброй ночи"
     }
 }
```

В данный метод передаете текущее время, возвращенную фразу подставляете куда вам надо